# Sharepoint server 2010 configuring search

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-server, search-results, search-scope

Can anyone provide or link to a general overview of how to setup and configure search in Sharepoint 2010. I see scopes and rules and have setup crawl jobs but I am trying to figure out the best way to limit search results and provide users access to that limited result set.

For example, what would be the best way to setup search for single library (we'll call it TPS reports). If I have a document library for TPS reports, how do I setup a search to only include results from this library and then how do I present my end users the opportunity for a drop down or something to only search TPS reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating scopes for document library

**Creating Search Scope**

1. Site Settings -> Site collection settings
2. Under Site Collection Administration -> Search Scopes
3. Click "New Scope"
4. Enter name, select "Search Dropdown"
5. Click Ok
6. Click Add Rules
7. Select Web Address
8. Enter Folder: = library path
9. Set Behavior = Required
10. Wait for 15 minutes so the scope will be ready!

Create a new page and add following webpart

- Search Box
- Search Core Results
- Search Paging

**Search Box**

Edit properties and set "Target search result page URL" as the page URL created above

**Search Core Results**

Edit properties and enter Location = None and Scope = "Name of scope created above"

Stop editing page and start searching!

Comment: This is perfect